# SharePoint 2019 (on-premises) Modern Search does not show results to anonymous users

Tags: search-results, modern-experience, 2019, anonymous-access

I have SharePoint server 2019 (on-premises) Communication site (Modern UI). I have set it up for anonymous access. Anonymous users can view all pages of the site without any issues except for search results.
It redirects to search page alright but does not show results nor does it show even the search controls.
The screenshot below shows the modern search results page header to logged in users.
[image]

The screenshot below shows the modern search results page header to anonymous users
[image]

Now here is the weirdest part, you'd think I must not have enabled the anonymous access properly but no, that's not the problem. To test this hypothesis, I just have to check the results in classic search. And voila! the results show up for anonymous users. Screenshot below.
[image]

If anonymous user simply switches back to the modern search, it shows blank search. Switches again to classic search, it shows results correctly.

So, clearly it is not the access issue. Does anybody have an idea what might be going on with Modern search in SP 2019 (on-premises)? Really appreciate the help, guys.

Comment: What patch level are you at?

Comment: Hi, Trevor. 
Patch is 16.0.10337.12109

Comment: You're at RTM -- remember Microsoft has a rolling support for SharePoint releases, so RTM is no longer under support. In addition, you should be patching on a monthly basis. There are a number of fixes for anonymous access and Comm sites for 2019. Try applying the Feb 2021 PU which came out yesterday. https://support.microsoft.com/help/4493194 and https://support.microsoft.com/help/4493193. Re-test and determine if this is still an issue post-patch.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/product-servicing-policy/updated-product-servicing-policy-for-sharepoint-2019

Comment: Thanks, Trevor. I installed both the patches, it didn't show the search results but at least now it is showing the search box and filter controls below the ribbon which it wasn't showing even that before the patches. So, I guess, I need to look into some more of the patches, right?